# Fetch OMDB API 2 times

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to fetch OMDB API to get a list of movies IDs and limit them to 3 and then map over them to get detailed info for each movie.

I tried to use map to iterate over each movie ID and then do fetch and pass the ID to the movie details end point but for some reason I'm doing something wrong and I get an empty object.

here's my attempt

```
export const load = async () => {
await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${SECRET_API_KEY}&s=avengers`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const respones = data.Search.map((m) =>
            fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${SECRET_API_KEY}&i=${m.imdbID}`).then((res) => res.json()),
        );

        Promise.all(respones).then((movies) => {
            return movies
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That's so because you only fetch for the first item.

Comment: I tried using map and do the fetch inside it but I always get an empty object!

I googled it and learned about Promise.all but for some reason I can't get it to work

Comment: @AhmedEmad Please [edit] your question to show us that attempt

Comment: @Bergi I have edited my question to explain my attempt, thank you

Comment: @AhmedEmad That should more or less work, just replace `return movies` by `console.log(movies)` (or whatever you want to do with them). If you really want to return them from the `load` function, you're also missing a `return` in front of the `Promise.all(…)` promise.

Comment: Btw, try not to mix `.then()` and `await` syntax. You can transform every `.then()` into an equivalent `await` expression. Probably you've seen examples using `Promise.all` with only `then` but you already had use `async`/`await` in your code. Try searching for examples of how to use `Promise.all` with `async`/`await` syntax specifically.

Comment: @Bergi thank you, It worked. however when I try to use Promise.all with async/await I got stuck, tbh I'm still learning promises, I always get an empty array when I map over the IDs and do fetch with the each ID and then await Promise.all 

What do I miss?